# How to fix listview checkbox behaviour?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created Listbox with property `checkboxes == true`, but the problem that I had was that I was needed to click twice on the line in order to set it checked. I was needed to change it in such a way that I can click on the line just once and the line set as checked. What I did is added mouseClick event:

```
        private void Cbl_folders_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedListViewItemCollection selectedItemsList = Cbl_folders.SelectedItems;

            if(selectedItemsList.Count > Constants.EMPTY_COUNT)
            {
                selectedItemsList[0].Checked = !selectedItemsList[0].Checked;
            }
        }
```

And everything works fine, first, click on the line set the line as checked the second click on the line set the line as unchecked. But then I found out that if you clicked on the line and set this line as checked and then you click on the **checkbox** on the other line, so your first line that was checked changes the state to unchecked. Why? Because I am tracking mouseDown event and even when I click on the checkbox on the other line mouse down event looks on selected items and the obviously selected item is the first line that was clicked.

I understand that it is possible to add some flags and look where was a click and so on, but it seems overcomplicated, I feel like there is should be a simpler solution.

Comment: What's your ListView Mode? What's the expected behavior when user clicks on a CheckBox, should the Item get selected, what if the user uncheck item?

Comment: @RezaAghaei what do you mean ListView mode? It is regular listview just with checkbox property == true. Behavior should be like this - when I click on the line it has to change the state (checked = !checked) and the same if I click on checkbox. For example - I clicked on first line it changed from unchecked to checked then I clicked on the checkbox on the second line it also changed the state, then I click on the first line but this time on the checkbox and it change the state from checked to unchecked and then I click on the second line and it is again change the state

Comment: @RezaAghaei to make a long story short doesn't matter if I click on the line or on the checkbox it should change the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the `MouseDown` event to switch the [ListViewItem.Checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.checked?view=netframework-4.7.2) property when you click over the label area. To get info about the clicked area, call the [ListView.HitTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.hittest?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListView.HitTest);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which returns a [ListViewHitTestInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewhittestinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListViewHitTestInfo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) object and check the [Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewhittestinfo.location?view=netframework-4.7.2) property, the property returns one of the [ListViewHitTestLocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewhittestlocations?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListViewHitTestLocations);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) values.

```cs
private void Cbl_folders_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Cbl_folders.CheckBoxes)
    {
        var ht = Cbl_folders.HitTest(e.Location);

        if (ht.Item != null && ht.Location == ListViewHitTestLocations.Label)
            ht.Item.Checked = !ht.Item.Checked;
    }
}
```

This way, the items are checked/unchecked by the mouse also when you click outside their check boxes areas (determined by the `ListViewHitTestLocations.StateImage` value).